# Performing land cover classification over whole country

Tags: qgis-3, classification, sentinel-2, land-classification

I am doing land cover classification over the whole country of Djibouti.

I am downloading Sentinel 2 images for this purpose. I have realised doing land cover classification over a large area needs downloading several images as I was used to smaller regions prior to this.

My question is, is there a simpler way to do land cover classification over a whole country without downloading several images, doing atmospheric correction (and other preprocessing procedures) where such kind of procedures may be faced with time constraints.

I hear coding may assist but I am not good in this area. Anyone who has had such a similar workload can advise me. I am using QGIS 3.14

Comment: Without scripting and without downloading is not really possible. Without downloading but with some amount of scripting there are cloud tools like Sentinel Hub or Google Earth Engine. You might also want to look at land cover maps which are already available, like Copernicus Land Cover for Africa or the MODIS Land Cover product

Answer (score 1):

Normally you have to mosaic them together, as the tiles only cover small areas. Maybe you will be able to find bigger tiles on google earth engine (https://earthengine.google.com/). The may have prepossessed the data, otherwise it will be much faster to mosaic the data on their plattform.